# Copying files from one server to another using a batch

Tags: cmd

I want to transfer data from a specific folder to another computer from the server, but I just started to study the baht files until I can manage it, please help

Below is an example that I have already used, but it does not copy.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
net use R:"\\10.21.203.120\New folder" /user:EUROPE\AnzhelikaKAst 
NurSultan!2019
md "R:\olo"
xcopy C:"\\10.21.199.227\New folder\olo" "R:\olo" /S /V /Y
net use R: /DELETE
[enter image description here][1]pause
```

I hope for your help and support

Comment: Angelica normally `c:` is the local drive and not available for mapping. Try `X:`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps...

```
net use R: "\\10.21.203.120\New folder NurSultan!2019" /user:EUROPE\AnzhelikaKAst NurSultan!2019 
md "R:\olo"
xcopy "C:\New folder\olo" "R:\olo" /S /V /Y  
net use R: /DELETE  

pause
```